# Core Bluetooth LE and Classical in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm research about Core Bluetooth. And I have any questions, could you please help me explain more about this:

1. What's difference between Core Bluetooth LE and Classical ?
2. I can implement Core bluetooth LE to connect other iOS devices ?
3. Is UUID used to? How can get UUID of devices?

Now, i need to implement application allow connect to count step device and get data from it. How can i do that? That device using Bluetooth LE. If can, you can show me tutorial or example code?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older bluetooth is a streaming protocol, and requires that the devices be paired. Apple only allows developers with a special license to develop Bluetooth peripherals.

Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) or Bluetooth 4.0 is a low energy polling interface where devices (peripherals) advertise services that they offer and devices that want to use those services ("centrals", in BLE terms) subscribe to those services.

BLE sends data in very short bursts. The transmitted power is lower than "classic" bluetooth, and the transmissions are MUCH shorter.

UUID is used to identify different services offered by BLE devices.

As for tutorials or example code, I don't have any on hand. I've been working with iBeacons so far, which is a specific protocol built on top of BLE. However, Google is your friend.

Comment: As you said, in my case,Count steps device (peripheral) auto advertise its services. And my app only can Scan this device and get data from it?