# iOS Bluetooth LE connection

Tags: ios, sockets, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying connect with a bluetooth hardware (ConnectBlue) using the Core Bluetooth. I can connect to the hardware and read the basic information like name and another infos, but I can't receive the updates that the hardware is sending. The manufacturer told me to create a serial connection, but I didn't find how do that.
With this same hardware I could connect with Android by socket using the method

```
bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID);
```

So I believe I'll need create this socket connection with the iOS to? Is that right? and how can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Please refer this link to know more about Bluetooth connections using Central and Peripheral managers http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/39707371281/core-bluetooth-for-ios-6-core-bluetooth-was

Comment: Can you share with us the name of the device you are dealing with? It would be easier to give useful feedback on your question.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have said, Apple does not permit serial stream connections to Bluetooth devices except as part of the MFI program and the external accessory framework.  You will need to find out if your device publishes data using Bluetooth 4.0/Bluetooth Low Energy characteristics.  The "LightBlue" app on the app store is a useful utility for discovering BLE devices, their services and published characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135884/core-bluetooth-le-and-classical-in-ios?rq=1), you are not allowed to read streaming data from your bluetooth device using low energy. Reading streaming data is only available using Classical bluetooth and to developers with a special license from Apple.

Comment: Thank you, I've  read about the MFI license but the manufacturer told me that is possible to connect and take this informations without it. So I'm trying to found a way to do that. :( 
He told me about use a serial port to take it.

Comment: Oh well, if you find a way to do that without licensing, i'm curious about it !

Comment: Connecting without MFi is possible only for the supported bluetooth profiles. You cannot open an SPP connection without authentication. If the device has MFi, then the External Accessory Framework can be used to communicate with it. Your manufacturer probably tells that you can read the same stream over BLE characteristics. Core Bluetooth does not have streaming support, you need to implement it.

Comment: Hi @allprog, I have some doubts about your comment, could you help me? "Connecting without MFi is possible ... supported bluetooth profiles", what you mean with profiles? "You cant open an SPP without auth.", auth you are talking about MFI? ".stream over BLE characteristics", sorry. I didn't understand. "CoreBluetooth does not have streaming support, you need to implement it.", do you mean create a connect without use Corebluetooth, do you have something to help on it? About the stream I  mean update, the device send the position variation(accelerometer), and send it to me. Thank you very much